# Redefine count-leaves as an accumulation

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

> Exercise 2.35.  Redefine count-leaves
> from section [2.2.2](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html) as an accumulation:
>
> ```
> (define (count-leaves t) (accumulate <??> <??> (map <??> <??>)))
> ```

I wrote the following:

```
(define (accumulate op initial sequence)
  (if (null? sequence)
      initial
      (op (car sequence)
          (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence)))))

(define (count-leaves t)
  (accumulate +
              0
              (map (lambda (subtree)
                     (if (pair? subtree) 
                         (count-leaves subtree)
                         1))
                   t)))

(define a (list 1 2 (list 1) (list 1 2 (list 2 (list 1 2)))))
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't handle the case of only a single leaf, i.e.

```
 (count-leaves 'leaf)
```

but I guess that's a side-effect of the original problem formulation. A cleaner solution would be

```
(define (count-leaves t)
  (if (pair? t)
      (accumulate + 0 (map count-leaves t))
      1)))
```

also because it's shorter but this doesn't fit the pattern of the original exercise.

Incidentally, in this case the standard Scheme procedure apply would be enough because the Scheme + routine takes in an arbitrary number of arguments, and you could write just:

```
(define (count-leaves t)
  (if (pair? t)
      (apply + (map count-leaves t))
      1)))
```